# Weak star limit in $L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose that you know that $v_N$ is such that :

- $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$, $v_N \in \mathcal{C}^0(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and $\partial_t v_N \in L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ ($\Omega$ an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary).
- $(v_N)_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a weak star limit, $v$, in $L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$  and $(\partial_t v_N)_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a weak star limit, $\partial_t v$, in $L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

Is it true that $\liminf_{N\to + \infty} \left\| v_N(T)\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \ge \left\| v(T)\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 $ ? And if it is, how can I prove such a statement ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should note that your first bullet implies $v_N \in W^{1,\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

Since
$\int_a^T \partial_t v_N(t) \, dt = v_N(T) - v_N(a)$, we have
$\int_0^T \,\int_a^T \partial_t v_N(t) \, dt \, da = \int_0^T t \, \partial_tv_N(t) \, dt = T \, v_N(T) - \int_0^T v_N(t) \, dt.$
Since the functions $t \mapsto 1$ and $t \mapsto t$ belong to $L^1(0,T)$, you have
\begin{align*}\lim T \, v_n(T) &= \lim T \, v_N(T) - \int_0^T v_N(t) \, d t + \int_0^T v_N (t) \, d t
\\&\to
\lim T \, v(T) - \int_0^T v(t) \, d t + \int_0^T v (t) \, d t
= T \, v(T)\end{align*}
This shows $v_N(T) \to v(T)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and hence the desired estimate.

Comment: I need to compare the $L^2$ norm in space of $v_N(T)$ and $v(T)$ and I don't see how I can compare this two norms with your proof.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my proof. Actually, I proved the convergence of the terminal value in $L^2(\Omega)$.